# prove that if $p$ is a prime number, then $\sqrt{p}$ is an irrational number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

- $\sqrt{p}$ is rational.
- $\sqrt{p}=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a,b$ are integers with $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
- $a^2=b^2p$.

Since $p$ divides $a^2$, $p$ divides $a$.

- $a=kp$.
- $a^2=k^2p^2=b^2p$
- $p=\frac{b^2}{k^2}\Rightarrow\sqrt{p}=\frac{b}{k}\Rightarrow\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{k}$
- $b^2=ak\Rightarrow b=\sqrt{ak}$.
- $\sqrt{p}=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{ak}}=\frac{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{k}}$ which has $\gcd(a,b)=\sqrt{a}\neq 1$ , a contradiction.

($a\neq 1$ because the only number that divides 1 is 1, but 1 is not a prime from $a=kp$)

Hence, $p$ is irrational. Is this legit?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, my proof is a little bit different from what you have shared the link if you look through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude like so, since you have  supposed that $gcd(a,b)=1$ at the beginning, then $p$ divides $a$ and $k^2p^2=b^2p$ implies that $pk^2=b^2$ this implies that $p$ divides $b$ contradiction.

Comment: is my way of taking out $\sqrt{a}$ and show that their $\gcd(a,b)=\sqrt{a}$ correct strategy then ?

Comment: how you know that $\sqrt a$ is an integer ?

Answer (score 2):

Every square number has an even number of prime divisors. Hence the number of prime divisors of $a^2$ is even where their number in $pb^2$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

By way of contradiction, assume $\sqrt{p}$ is rational. Then there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $b\neq 0$ such that $\sqrt{p} = \frac{a}{b}$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $\text{gcd}(a,b) \neq 1$

We can make this assumption, because we still lose no generality.

Now using  $\text{gcd} (a,b) = d \neq 1$. Then we can write $a = d \cdot a'$ and $b = d \cdot b'$, for some relatively prime integers $a'$ and $b'$.

Hence
$$
\sqrt{p} = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{d a'}{d b'} = \frac{a'}{b'},
$$
So we have shown that $\sqrt{p}$ is a ratio of two relatively prime integers.

Comment: $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ or not? You assumed one thing and used the opposite assumption in your proof.

Comment: Is my way of proving correct?